# I am looking for video game cassette 4 in 1

Tags: nes

So, I am looking for a video game cassette 4 in 1. I used to play back in 2005-2007 this cassette contains 4 games

1. Robin Hood
2. Not sure the name of this one but in this game, a fireman catches people who jump from a building that on fire.

So actually I am looking for is 3 and 4 the game that I don't remember that much but those are fun games. I think 3rd one is logical games that's the only thing I remember.

I am sharing game photos that I remember.

[image: Robin Hood]

[image: Flying Hero]

The below photo is a cassette example, not the actual one I am looking for.

[image]

The below photo is a TV Game console that I used to play on cassette 4 in 1.

[image]

I am also sharing the gameplay youtube video.

[Super Robin Hood NES - Completed Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cL3kpEPMy2U)

[Flying Hero Walkthrough/Gameplay NES](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H-r_OQH_oU)

Comment: Sorry, but screenshots that you remember being correct fall outside of our game identification questions.

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have found what you're looking for.

Our old friends Codemasters published Super Robin Hood in 1986 for the Amstrad CPC, Commodore 64, Atari ST, Amiga, NES, and the ZX Spectrum.

In 1990, Codemasters, which now owned the game as developers, worked with publisher Camerica to release [Quattro Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quattro_compilations#Quattro_Adventure) for the NES and Commodore 64:

[image]

This 4 pack of games included Linus Spacehead, Super Robin Hood, Boomerang Kid, and Treasure Island Dizzy. This is the only record of Super Robin Hood appearing in a 4-game collection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but I did not play that robin hood game. I just edited my question and shared the gameplay youtube video links.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what else to tell you. The specimens you provided, even your edited in video link, points to Super Robin Hood for the NES. This game was ported to only one 4 pack collection, which was Quattro Adventure, at least as far as I can find.